# Ubuntu 18.10 install on Desktop with no OS and UEFI bios crashes

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, uefi, 18.10

I tried installing Ubuntu 18.10 on my new desktop. I burned the 18.10 iso file to a USB and tried to boot Ubuntu. What happens after is that ~30 seconds into the installation process, after running the Ubuntu GUI, the mouse starts to freeze and the peripherals all die.

I tried setting nomodeset but it didn't change anything. I think it might be a problem with the fact I have an RTX 2080 Ti GPU and no driver installed yet.

Does anybody know what my next step should be?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the `nomodeset` boot parameter for the live session/installtion and then again when booting for the first time until you actually install the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Hi Gabriella, I tried that. Doesn't work. Here is a more detailed thread of the problem: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/amvdhr/ubuntu_1804_crashing_during_installation/

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia has released a Linux driver for the RTX cards (410.93), but I don't know if they have been added to the Ubuntu repositories yet.  I didn't see it listed when I searched the repositories with Synaptic.

You might have to install it manually, which is not hard but you have to follow the instructions in the readme file that is part of the driver package *exactly*.

Comment: Is it possible to install a driver manually with no OS though? I thought it was impossible...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  You'd have to install Ubuntu first, then install the Nvidia driver.

Comment: Yeah the problem is I cannot install Ubuntu...

Comment: @rbmorse https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112625/ubuntu-18-10-install-on-desktop-with-no-os-and-uefi-bios-crashes/1112629#comment1843594_1112625 Again, please pay attention to the question, even when the question is dumb.